# Changing array into an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

In Javascript, I am looking for the best way to convert:

```
var data1 = [["ff",4],["gg",3],["dd",2],["hh",1]];
```

to:

```
var data2 = [
  {word: "ff", frequency: 4},
  {word: "gg", frequency: 3},
  {word: "dd", frequency: 2},
  {word: "hh", frequency: 1}
]
```

First would create an object:

```
var data2 = {};
```

Then run it through a For loop to populate it with the data1 content.

```
for (i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
  data2[word] = data1[i][0];
  data2[frequency] = data1[i][1];
}
```

Comment: Your first `data` assignment is not valid JS and is missing, at the very least, an opening square bracket.

Comment: I would create an object then populate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Map the elements (tuples) in the array to corresponding objects:

```
data2 = data1.map(function(pair) {
   return {word: pair[0], frequency: pair[1]};
});
```

In an ES6 environment:

```
data2 = data1.map(([word, frequency]) => ({word, frequency}));
```

My, how succinct.

Comment: I like how the ES6 code is able to figure out the appropriate property names for the new object by itself.  I thought it was a mistake till I tried it, very cool, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A more generic solution with an array of keys:

```js
var data = [['ff', 4], ['gg', 3], ['dd', 2], ['hh', 1]],
    keys = ['word', 'frequency'],
    dataObj = data.map(function (a) {
        return keys.reduce(function (r, b, i) {
            r[b] = a[i];
            return r;
        }, {});
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(dataObj, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thank you but trying to be as clear as possible or as simple as possible. My original converter is elementary at best but not elegant. 
torazaburo's answer brings your answer one more step up. Super!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of utility functions in lodash/underscore that can do this:
https://lodash.com/docs#zipObject

If you want to implement your own version, then under the hood, they are just creating a new object, then running through the array of arrays and setting the keyname with the first and the value with the second: a simple for loop, just as Blazemonger notes.

Comment: Well, `zipObject` does not (at least by itself) do what he wants.

Answer (score -3):

Here is my quick solution:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {

    var data = [['ff',4],['gg',3],['dd',2],['hh',1]];

    var converted = [];

    $(data).each(function()
    {
      converted.push( {word: this[0], frequency: this[1]});
    });

    console.dir(converted);

});

</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Why on earth would you use `$.each`?

Comment: Thanks -- I think your loop is better than the for loop  etc:

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery, then at least use `$.map`, which takes care of creating the array so you don't have to declare it yourself and push the elements onto it one by one.

Comment: I really would not like to use JQuery.